# Backgroundworker ReportProgress delay

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a problem with the backgroundworker's reportprogress function. I read data records using an odbc driver in the worker's doWork function and after every row I read I call the reportProgress function to add this row to the display. Sometimes this works, sometimes the report progress waits till I read an arbitrary number of records, example 6, and then adds 6 records identical to the last record read. So for example in the prints in the below code I get things like:

```
ROW: 1: 00000001
ABS 1: 00000001
ROW: 2: 00000002
ROW: 3: 00000003
ROW: 4: 00000010
ROW: 5: 00000011
ROW: 6: 00000012
ROW: 7: 00000013
ROW: 8: 00000014
ROW: 9: 00000015
ROW: 10: 00000015
ABS 10: 00000015
ABS 10: 00000015
ABS 10: 00000015
ROW: 11: 00000016
ABS 11: 00000016
ABS 11: 00000016
ABS 11: 00000016
ABS 11: 00000016
ABS 11: 00000016
ABS 11: 00000017
ROW: 12: 00000017
ABS 12: 00000017
ABS 12: 00000017
```

Someone suggested a Thread.sleep after I call report progress but I prefer not to do this.

This is my code in the DoWork:

```
while (!terminateRead)
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
            {
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    row[i] = reader.GetString(i);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Read Process interrupted");
        }
        currentRow++;
        double perc = ((double)currentRow / rowCount) * 100.0;
        int percentageComplete = Convert.ToInt32(perc);
        Console.WriteLine("ROW: " + currentRow + ": " + row[0]);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentageComplete, row);
    }
```

and in my report progress

```
/* Function to display the progress percentage to the user and add rows copied
 * from the Btrieve table to the view.
 * */
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,   ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // string array of the data read in the populateRows() function.
    string[] row = (string[])e.UserState;
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    label1.Text = "Loaded " + e.ProgressPercentage + "% (" + currentRow + "\\" + rowCount + ") of the file";
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    Console.WriteLine("ABS " +currentRow + ": " + row[0]);
    //dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow-1].HeaderCell.Value = (currentRow).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Which version of .Net you used ?

Comment: I'd take out the `Console.WriteLine` lines - your UI thread and your background worker will be competing with each other to obtain exclusive access to it.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ka89zff4)

> The call to the ReportProgress method is asynchronous and returns
>   immediately. The ProgressChanged event handler executes on the thread
>   that created the BackgroundWorker.

So, background worker does not wait for `ProgressChanged` event to be handled and continues reading rows and raising events. On the other hand all handlers are executed on you main thread which has another job to do, so they are just scheduled. Also keep in mind that handling of this event may take more time, than doing one step in processing. That's explains why processing goes faster.

But why you have handling in batches? Threads do not execute some method and exit - they have some time for doing job. That's why you see several handlers executed in a row - its just time window which was given to main thread for processing. If there is several handlers waiting to be executed, they all starts executing.

And last thing is `currentRow` issue. In handler you see `currentRow` value of last row which was processed, because you are using same variable in two threads. Handler can't guess which was value of `currentRow` when event was raised, until you pass that value to handler. If you don't want to create class for passing these parameters between threads, you can use simple array or dynamics:

```
 backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage, new object[]{ currentRow, row });
```

Then in handler you can get `currentRow` value from time when event was raised:

```
 object[] state = (object[])e.UserState;
 string[] row = (string[])state[1];
 int currentRow = (int)state[0];
```

Don't forget to make `currentRow` local to `DoWork` handler - it should not be global variable in your form.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `Console.WriteLine()` in `DoWork()` method, it should be either part of `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler or `ReportProgress` method. The job of `DoWork` method should be either to process the long running work or report the progress and it should ***not*** interact with the GUI thread (like it should not call Console methods).

Please move this line out of `DoWork()` method and call in `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` or `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler (you would need to add an event handler if you have not added):

```
Console.WriteLine("ROW: " + currentRow + ": " + row[0]);
```

For more info on BackgroundWorker component, please see:

- [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.100%29)
- [Understanding C#: BackgroundWorker tutorial for multithreaded GUIs](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/06/understanding-c-using-backgrou.html)

Comment: I'm not sure that was the problem. I only put in the prints because the displayed data looked wrong. Removing the prints still resulted in duplicates in the data grid view. I upvoted thought for the information.

I managed to fix the problem using threading and forcing the do work function to wait for the report progress to complete

Comment: @O.Fouda, The `DoWork` method of BackgroundWorker already spawns a thread, you should not use additional threads. Just refer the links and understand the concepts, and you should be able to achieve what you want *just by BackgroundWorker*.